# Recentering state abbreviation on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I modified the shape profile to add Hawaii and Alaska and so my data frame is using a different long, lat coordinates than the stock state coordinates provided by `maps` package (`map_data("state")`) shown below

```
states <- data.frame(state.center, state.abb)
states
           x       y state.abb
1   -86.7509 32.5901        AL
2  -127.2500 49.2500        AK
3  -111.6250 34.2192        AZ
4   -92.2992 34.7336        AR
5  -119.7730 36.5341        CA
```

My data frame have coordinates as follow.

[image]

When I plot it using the code below I get a map without any state abbreviation labels.

```
p <- function(data, brks, title) {
  ggp <- ggplot() + 
    geom_polygon(data = data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, 
                                  fill = IMSUB), color = "black", size = 0.15) + 
    scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-1,1), breaks = c(-1, 0, 1), labels=c("Trump", 0, "Clinton"), low = "red", mid = "white",
                         high = "blue", midpoint = 0, space = "Lab",
                         na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar") + 
    theme_nothing(legend = TRUE) + labs(title = title, fill = "") + 
    geom_text(data = states, aes(x = x, y = y, label = state.abb), size = 3)
  return(ggp)
}
```

[image]

i feel like I can replace the coordinates in `states` data frame with one in `us50` but I am not sure how to replace them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it with the size inside the `aes()`?

```
 geom_text(data=state, aes(x y, label = state.abb, size=3)
```

If not, this other method will likely work instead, just replace the geom_text line:

```
with(states, annotate(geom="text", x = x y=y, label = state.abb, size = 3))
```

It should apply annotation using states, as text with x & y as your lat and long..That should work.

Comment: Looking even closer, it does look like your coordinate systems are not the same...Although ggplot could plot either system, they still need to be in the same one...see what happens if you get them in the same coordinate system. You can use the package 'sp' for that...